# MySQL returns last inserted when querying IS NULL

Tags: mysql, select, insert, null, auto-increment

Whenever I do a `SELECT` statement with `WHERE id is NULL` directly after an `INSERT`, I get the last inserted row.

I am using MySQL 5.1.73.

It happens directly in the MySQL shell; here is my console:

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE testing (
    ->     id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     name VARCHAR(200),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO testing (name) VALUES ('test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM testing WHERE id IS NULL;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | test |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Is this a bug or is it a setting I am missing?

Comment: At a guess, perhaps it does this because that's how the "last inserted ID" feature is implemented?

Comment: I think the problem is with `$query->closeCursor();`

Comment: @Saty Removing the closeCursor still results in the same result.

Comment: A comment by swordbeta to my "non-answer" contained: "With the same PHP version (5.4.16) but a different MySQL version (the latest MariaDB version) and couldn't reproduce this error."

Comment: I can't reproduce it in the MySQL shell in 5.5.43.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your MySQL version, and it has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: can't reproduce, mysql 5.6.23

Comment: sounds like a question more suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Updated my question with the answer.

Comment: Better post the answer as an answer ;-)

Comment: Post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer myself.
My version of MySQL (5.1.73, the last available on CentOS 6) has the setting [`sql_auto_is_null`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_auto_is_null) by default on, while newer versions don't:

> ```
> ╔═════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╗
> ║ System Variable (<= 5.5.2)  ║ Name             ║ sql_auto_is_null ║
> ║                             ║ Variable Scope   ║ Session          ║
> ║                             ║ Dynamic Variable ║ Yes              ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
> ║ System Variable (>= 5.5.3)  ║ Name             ║ sql_auto_is_null ║
> ║                             ║ Variable Scope   ║ Global, Session  ║
> ║                             ║ Dynamic Variable ║ Yes              ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
> ║ Permitted Values (<= 5.5.2) ║ Type             ║ boolean          ║
> ║                             ║ Default          ║ 1                ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
> ║ Permitted Values (>= 5.5.3) ║ Type             ║ boolean          ║
> ║                             ║ Default          ║ 0                ║
> ╚═════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╝
> ```
>
> If this variable is set to 1 (the default), then after a statement that successfully inserts an automatically generated `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, you can find that value by issuing a statement of the following form:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE auto_col IS NULL
> ```
>
> If the statement returns a row, the value returned is the same as if you invoked the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function. For details, including the return value after a multiple-row insert, see [Section 12.14, “Information Functions”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html). If no `AUTO_INCREMENT` value was successfully inserted, the [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statement returns no row.
>
> The behavior of retrieving an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value by using an [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) comparison is used by some ODBC programs, such as Access. See [Obtaining Auto-Increment Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html). This behavior can be disabled by setting [`sql_auto_is_null`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_auto_is_null) to 0.
>
> The default value of [`sql_auto_is_null`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_auto_is_null) is 0 as of MySQL 5.5.3, and 1 for earlier versions.